# Anyone tried assumeutxo yet?

Tags: full-node, assume-utxo

I am attempting to use assumeutxo, but I may be overlooking something. I attempted to use my own snapshots from another node, but I consistently encountered the following error, where `<BLOCKHASH>` is present on the current blockheaders:

```
Unable to load utxo snapshot, assumeutxo block hash in snapshot not recognized <BLOCKHASH>
```

[image]

Comment: FYI I just updated this project and now i'm hosting the assumeutxo files as well: 

https://bitcoin-snapshots.jaonoct.us

* mainnet one, as Ava said, needs a [patch](https://github.com/jaonoctus/docker-bitcoind/blob/165e073036ea7bd1bef0098fa3d1db1b29ac0b12/26.0/patches/assumeutxo.patch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, AssumeUTXO uses hardcoded block and snapshot hashes so you can only load specific snapshots. It does not work generically with any snapshot. If you want to use different snapshot blocks, then you will need to modify the source code and recompile.

There is no snapshot data set for mainnet yet, so you cannot use AssumeUTXO on mainnet without modifying the code.

The snapshot info for testnet can be found at https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/3695ecbf680a66b718f97d504308578d001eec49/src/kernel/chainparams.cpp#L269 and for signet at https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/3695ecbf680a66b718f97d504308578d001eec49/src/kernel/chainparams.cpp#L378